# c# datagridview how to align a TextBox over the header

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, .net-4.0, datagridviewcolumn

I have this problem: I need to put a `TextBox` over the column header of my `DataGridView`.. to find this I start reading the rectangle of the column to retrieve the left position and the width..

```
Rectangle rec = dgv.GetColumnDisplayRectangle(mycolumnIndex, true);
```

and this works fine, but if the grid contains no rows, the `Rectangle` is 0..

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce, the Rectangle is always retuning the location and width of the Header, no matter whether ther are any rows or not.

Comment: thanks @TaW, but for me with visual studio 2013 return a rectangle 0,0,0,0 if no rows are selected, 'cause the rectangle is the column area, below the header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether there are **any** rows or not or **selected** rows or not, the `Rectangle` returned from `GetColumnDisplayRectangle` is always correct for any **visible**  column.

If it is `Empty` for you,  then  your  `Column` is either **invisible** or **scrolled** outside of the the display area.

You will need to set the location of your `TextBox` or whatever `Control` you place there, both after a `ColumnWidthChanged` and a `Scroll` event. Also whenever you **hide** or **show** Columns.

Here is a working example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Parent = dataGridView1;              // nest the TextBox
    placeControl(dataGridView1, textBox1, 2);     // place it over the 3rd column header
}


private void dataGridView1_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    placeControl(dataGridView1, textBox1, 2);
}

private void dataGridView1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    placeControl(dataGridView1, textBox1, 2);
}

void placeControl(DataGridView dgv, Control ctl, int index)
{
    Rectangle R = dgv.GetColumnDisplayRectangle(index, true );  // or false
    ctl.Location = R.Location;
    ctl.Size = new Size(R.Width, dgv.ColumnHeadersHeight);
}
```